# Path mapping in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm currently working on a javascript project. I usually use typescript and ts has the path mapping feature. Is there something similar in javascript ?

TS path mapping:

```
"compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "src",
         ...
        "paths": {
            "@app/*": ["app/*"],
            "@config/*": ["app/_config/*"],
            "@environment/*": ["environments/*"],
            "@shared/*": ["app/_shared/*"],
            "@helpers/*": ["helpers/*"]
        },
        ...
```

Comment: is this in your `package.json` file?

Comment: also what bundler are you using in your project?

Comment: No, this snippet is not in my `package.json` or my code at all. I just added it to have a path mapping example.

Comment: so then what do you actually want to do then/

Comment: I am using webpack (it is a react project created with create-react-app)

Comment: then just use `create-react-app` again and select `javascript` and not `typescript`, simple

Comment: You can set an [alias](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvealias) in the Webpack config, which is kinda the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Webpack this feature is available via [`resolve.alias`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvealias). The configuration is similar, for example via `webpack.config.js`:

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@app": path.resolve(__dirname, 'app/'),
      "@config": path.resolve(__dirname, 'app/config/'),
      "@environment": path.resolve(__dirname, 'environments/'),
      // Etc
    },
  },
};
```